# Delete a row with primary key Id

Tags: sql, asp.net-web-api, postman

I have deleted a row in sql DB using HTTPDelete command in asp.net core web api project, but when i try to insert a new row ,the primary key **Id** is getting auto incremented with the delete row Id. How to prevent it?
Ex:

|  | Id | Email | UserName | FirstName | LastName | PhoneNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | Test2@gmail.com | Test3 | Test4 | string | 12345678 |
| 2 | 6 | string | string | string | string | 0 |

```
Delete Function:
[HttpDelete]

public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteUser(int id)
{
if(_dbContext.Users == null)
{
return NotFound(nameof(DeleteUser));
}
var user = await _dbContext.Users.FindAsync(id);
if(user == null)
{
return NotFound($"{nameof(DeleteUser)}");
}
_dbContext.Users.Remove(user);
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
return Ok("Successfully deleted.");
}
}
Insert Function:
[HttpPost]

public async Task<ActionResult<User>> PostUser(User user)
{
_dbContext.Users.Add(user);
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetUser),new { id = user.Id }, user) ;
}
```

and if I try to manually insert id value, It is throwing the below error:

**Cannot Insert Explicit Value for Identity Column in Table when Identity Insert is Set to Off**

Comment: What version of SQL?  What is the definition of the primary key on the table?

Comment: Please format you code to be readable.

Comment: How is this related to the SQL _language_? (I see no SQL above, do you expect an SQL answer?)

Comment: The data that is stored is in sql db and the example given is the result set when execute the sql query.

Answer (score 0):

Given that error you are using SQL Server.

In SQL Server if you have an `identity` column to automatically generate the value of the `id` (or whatever the `identity` column is used) then you cannot specify a value for that id on insert. (There is a way to do this, but it is not suitable for general application use.)

Instead do not specify the value of `id`, it will be populated on the entity instance after saving changes.

If you do need to specify the `id` value then alter the column  to not be an `identity` column. And your code needs to ensure each `insert` has a unique value for the `id`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But if i deleted all the rows and insert a new row. I need to get the Id starting from '1' instead of getting an auto increment of Id from the deleted row. How can i achieve this?

Comment: @SravyaDamodar that is not not how identity columns work. You can do this manually (see [`DBCC CHECKIDENT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) but this is an admin operation that an application should not be doing). Also there is no guarantee that values will not be skipped (server failover or restart can do this).

Comment: @SravyaDamodar Worth noting what is not included in the definition of an `identity` column: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#identity. Only what is specified can be relied on; anything else is up to you. If you want full control on values you will need to write code.

Comment: For my concern, I have created a extra table and place all the columns in the old table without giving identity column and insert the values in new table by taking values from old table  . Then drop the old one and rename new table with  old table name. For application wise, its not a suggestable approach but as per the requirement, i have gone through that way and its worked as expected. Kindly let me know if there is any other approach. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To insert the data manually you can use the command for the specific table:

```
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT Salaries ON;
```

But it is not feasible method to enter manually in an application development.

I didn't understoode the other part of your question clearly, But if you want to generate unique id having 8 digits or more every time a post request happens, U can use Timestamp to generate unique IDs or you can use Guid datatype in the Poco class.